# Create instance with dynamic generic type

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс допустим:

```
class Class<TData>
{

}
```

Есть сборка `assembly.dll`, которая загружается динамически, и вней содержится нужный тип "TData", допустим `NeedDataType`.
Как мне можно создать instance типа: `new Class<NeedDataType>()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class CustomClass<TData>
{
}

string assemblyPath = @"C:\assembly.dll";
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
Type needDataType = myAssembly.GetType("assembly.NeedDataType");
Type needGenericType = typeof (CustomClass<>).MakeGenericType(needDataType);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(needGenericType);
```

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417644/how-to-activate-a-generic-method-that-takes-an-action-as-its-parameter)